# background-image animation com CSS

Tags: background-image, css-animations

blz?

Eu tenho um "" com Parallax (parallaxie. js) e animação de imagem de fundo com CSS (KeyFrames).

Siga o link: https://codepen.Io/Aguinaldo-Aranda/Pen/zLJwrM

Acontece que a animação não está 100%, as vezes parece meio bugada, depois de alguns momentos, um minuto (as vezes menos), o tempo entre a transição de uma imagem de fundo e outra diminui, fica muito rápido... Eu pesquisei muito sobre este tipo de animação, eu testei vários exemplos, o código exemplificado em Codepen representa o melhor resultado que eu tenho.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Obrigado

```js
jQuery(function ($) {       
    $(".parallax").parallaxie({
            speed: 0.55,
            offset:0,
     });
  });
```

```css
html{
  overflow: visible;
}
body{
  color: #fff;
}
section{
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 140px 0;
}

.parallax {position: relative; background-size: cover; overflow: hidden; background-attachment: fixed;background-repeat: no-repeat; }

.no-transition *, .swiper-container *, .mfp-container *, .skillbar-bar-main *, .portfolio-grid *, .parallax, .header-searchbar *, .header-social-icon * { transition-timing-function:initial; -moz-transition-timing-function:initial; -webkit-transition-timing-function:initial; -o-transition-timing-function:initial; -ms-transition-timing-function:initial; transition-duration: 0s; -moz-transition-duration: 0s; -webkit-transition-duration: 0s; -o-transition-duration: 0s; -ms-transition-duration: 0s; }


.slidein {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    z-index: 0;
    /*animation-delay: 2s !important; */
    /*background-image: url(../images/bg_simulador.jpg); */
    -webkit-animation: slidein ease-in-out 5s both infinite;
    -moz-animation: slidein ease-in-out 5s both infinite;
    animation: slidein ease-in-out 5s both infinite; 
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_ibi-1-1920x1070.jpg);
  } 

  40% {
    background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_valclei-home-1920x1071.jpg);
  } 

  80% {
    background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_tecfil_2-1920x1070.jpg);
  }
  
  100% {
   background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_ibi-1-1920x1070.jpg);
  }

}
    
@-moz-keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_ibi-1-1920x1070.jpg);
  } 

  40% {
    background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_valclei-home-1920x1071.jpg);
  } 

  80% {
    background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_tecfil_2-1920x1070.jpg);
  }
  
  100% {
   background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_ibi-1-1920x1070.jpg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_ibi-1-1920x1070.jpg);
  } 

  40% {
    background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_valclei-home-1920x1071.jpg);
  } 

  80% {
    background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_tecfil_2-1920x1070.jpg);
  }
  
  100% {
   background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_ibi-1-1920x1070.jpg);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="http://static.theultrasoft.com/parallaxie/parallaxie.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<section id="simulador" class="parallax no-transition bg-img1 slidein conteudo_home">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
                <h3 class="text-uppercase alt-font text-blue font-weight-600">
                 Lorem Ipsumw
                </h3>
          <p>Nulla sit amet congue turpis. Cras sagittis lacus sit amet nulla molestie, sit amet sollicitudin velit dictum. Aenean a urna nec mi imperdiet molestie. Cras placerat arcu non condimentum elementum. Maecenas maximus ultricies magna, sed hendrerit elit pulvinar non. Sed suscipit eros eu sollicitudin hendrerit. Donec porta porttitor ullamcorper. Vestibulum vulputate nibh vel libero faucibus ornare. Curabitur vehicula tincidunt quam, ac suscipit leo ullamcorper quis. Pellentesque pulvinar metus vel leo porttitor facilisis. Morbi scelerisque consectetur justo nec placerat. Aliquam lorem lacus, gravida non tristique nec, viverra sed massa. Integer luctus, dolor scelerisque mattis lacinia, erat diam interdum augue, a consectetur ipsum massa sed enim. Nullam fermentum hendrerit dui. Nulla et eros sed odio facilisis iaculis id ut eros.

Phasellus facilisis non purus vitae ultricies. Curabitur at felis sed risus facilisis porttitor. Aliquam vitae feugiat purus, non aliquam quam. Integer in tellus eget purus mollis efficitur id ut ipsum. Donec egestas in ex vel rhoncus. Fusce sit amet eros ex. Donec facilisis neque eget nisi tincidunt, eu pulvinar arcu vestibulum. Suspendisse sit amet urna egestas, lacinia ligula nec, ultrices metus. Fusce rutrum lorem massa. Praesent lacinia ipsum vitae erat lobortis aliquam. Donec tincidunt ante id sapien vehicula aliquet. Sed dolor metus, vulputate eu euismod et, commodo quis turpis. Nam non nunc ac ante gravida porttitor eget vel orci.</p>
<p>Nulla sit amet congue turpis. Cras sagittis lacus sit amet nulla molestie, sit amet sollicitudin velit dictum. Aenean a urna nec mi imperdiet molestie. Cras placerat arcu non condimentum elementum. Maecenas maximus ultricies magna, sed hendrerit elit pulvinar non. Sed suscipit eros eu sollicitudin hendrerit. Donec porta porttitor ullamcorper. Vestibulum vulputate nibh vel libero faucibus ornare. Curabitur vehicula tincidunt quam, ac suscipit leo ullamcorper quis. Pellentesque pulvinar metus vel leo porttitor facilisis. Morbi scelerisque consectetur justo nec placerat. Aliquam lorem lacus, gravida non tristique nec, viverra sed massa. Integer luctus, dolor scelerisque mattis lacinia, erat diam interdum augue, a consectetur ipsum massa sed enim. Nullam fermentum hendrerit dui. Nulla et eros sed odio facilisis iaculis id ut eros.

Phasellus facilisis non purus vitae ultricies. Curabitur at felis sed risus facilisis porttitor. Aliquam vitae feugiat purus, non aliquam quam. Integer in tellus eget purus mollis efficitur id ut ipsum. Donec egestas in ex vel rhoncus. Fusce sit amet eros ex. Donec facilisis neque eget nisi tincidunt, eu pulvinar arcu vestibulum. Suspendisse sit amet urna egestas, lacinia ligula nec, ultrices metus. Fusce rutrum lorem massa. Praesent lacinia ipsum vitae erat lobortis aliquam. Donec tincidunt ante id sapien vehicula aliquet. Sed dolor metus, vulputate eu euismod et, commodo quis turpis. Nam non nunc ac ante gravida porttitor eget vel orci.</p>
<p>Nulla sit amet congue turpis. Cras sagittis lacus sit amet nulla molestie, sit amet sollicitudin velit dictum. Aenean a urna nec mi imperdiet molestie. Cras placerat arcu non condimentum elementum. Maecenas maximus ultricies magna, sed hendrerit elit pulvinar non. Sed suscipit eros eu sollicitudin hendrerit. Donec porta porttitor ullamcorper. Vestibulum vulputate nibh vel libero faucibus ornare. Curabitur vehicula tincidunt quam, ac suscipit leo ullamcorper quis. Pellentesque pulvinar metus vel leo porttitor facilisis. Morbi scelerisque consectetur justo nec placerat. Aliquam lorem lacus, gravida non tristique nec, viverra sed massa. Integer luctus, dolor scelerisque mattis lacinia, erat diam interdum augue, a consectetur ipsum massa sed enim. Nullam fermentum hendrerit dui. Nulla et eros sed odio facilisis iaculis id ut eros.

Phasellus facilisis non purus vitae ultricies. Curabitur at felis sed risus facilisis porttitor. Aliquam vitae feugiat purus, non aliquam quam. Integer in tellus eget purus mollis efficitur id ut ipsum. Donec egestas in ex vel rhoncus. Fusce sit amet eros ex. Donec facilisis neque eget nisi tincidunt, eu pulvinar arcu vestibulum. Suspendisse sit amet urna egestas, lacinia ligula nec, ultrices metus. Fusce rutrum lorem massa. Praesent lacinia ipsum vitae erat lobortis aliquam. Donec tincidunt ante id sapien vehicula aliquet. Sed dolor metus, vulputate eu euismod et, commodo quis turpis. Nam non nunc ac ante gravida porttitor eget vel orci.</p>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara no caso da sua animação é um "slideshow" simples, nem era precisa usar             `animation-direction` ou `animation-fill-mode`, acho que isso pode ter bugado seu slide. Outra coisa que reparei é que havia uma "tremida" entre uma imagem e outra. Isso é porque elas estavam com tamanhos diferentes.

Quando vc usa o `animation-direction: alternate` a animação chega ao fim e volta de traz para frente em vez de continuar e fazer o lood no sentido ideal, então quando a animação faz esse *backwards* da a impressão que ela deu uma acelerada... O `animation-fill-mode:both` serve apenas para o frame manter o estilo do primeiro e do última `@keyframe`, que no seu caso não faz diferença, pois é a mesma imagem no primeiro e no último slide e a classe `.slidein` não tem `background-image`, o `background-image` está direto no `@keyframes`

Documentação sobre `fill-mode`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Documentação sobre o `direction`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction

Todas deveriam medir `1920x1070` porém uma delas estava com `1920x1071` ai dava uma tremida na troca de image.

Fiz apenas uns ajustes na `animation` e acho que resolveu. Testa ai.

***OBS:*** O Snippet do StackOverflow não aceita links http, tem que ser https, por isso não funciona direito aqui, mas teste no seu projeto que deve funcionar

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <style>
        html {
            overflow: visible;
        }

        body {
            color: #fff;
        }

        section {
            width: 100%;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 140px 0;
        }

        .parallax {
            position: relative;
            background-size: cover;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .no-transition *,
        .swiper-container *,
        .mfp-container *,
        .skillbar-bar-main *,
        .portfolio-grid *,
        .parallax,
        .header-searchbar *,
        .header-social-icon * {
            transition-timing-function: initial;
            -moz-transition-timing-function: initial;
            -webkit-transition-timing-function: initial;
            -o-transition-timing-function: initial;
            -ms-transition-timing-function: initial;
            transition-duration: 0s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
            -o-transition-duration: 0s;
            -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
        }


        .slidein {
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100%;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 50%;
            z-index: 0;
            /*animation-delay: 2s !important; */
            /*background-image: url(../images/bg_simulador.jpg); */
            -webkit-animation: slidein ease-in-out 5s infinite;
            -moz-animation: slidein ease-in-out 5s infinite;
            animation: slidein ease-in-out 5s infinite;
        }


        @-moz-keyframes slidein {
            0% {
                background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_ibi-1-1920x1070.jpg);
            }

            40% {
                background-image: url(http://placecage.com/1920/1070);
            }

            80% {
                background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_tecfil_2-1920x1070.jpg);
            }

            100% {
                background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_ibi-1-1920x1070.jpg);
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes slidein {
            0% {
                background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_ibi-1-1920x1070.jpg);
            }

            40% {
                background-image: url(http://placecage.com/1920/1070);
            }

            80% {
                background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_tecfil_2-1920x1070.jpg);
            }

            100% {
                background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_ibi-1-1920x1070.jpg);
            }

        }

        @keyframes slidein {
            0% {
                background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_ibi-1-1920x1070.jpg);
            }

            40% {
                background-image: url(http://placecage.com/1920/1070);
            }

            80% {
                background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_tecfil_2-1920x1070.jpg);
            }

            100% {
                background-image: url(http://www.kzulo.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bg_ibi-1-1920x1070.jpg);
            }

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>








    <section id="simulador" class="parallax no-transition bg-img1 slidein conteudo_home">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h3 class="text-uppercase alt-font text-blue font-weight-600">
                        Lorem Ipsumw
                    </h3>
                    <p>Nulla sit amet congue turpis. Cras sagittis lacus sit amet nulla molestie, sit amet sollicitudin velit
                        dictum. Aenean a urna nec mi imperdiet molestie. Cras placerat arcu non condimentum elementum. Maecenas
                        maximus ultricies magna, sed hendrerit elit pulvinar non. Sed suscipit eros eu sollicitudin hendrerit.
                        Donec porta porttitor ullamcorper. Vestibulum vulputate nibh vel libero faucibus ornare. Curabitur
                        vehicula tincidunt quam, ac suscipit leo ullamcorper quis. Pellentesque pulvinar metus vel leo porttitor
                        facilisis. Morbi scelerisque consectetur justo nec placerat. Aliquam lorem lacus, gravida non tristique
                        nec, viverra sed massa. Integer luctus, dolor scelerisque mattis lacinia, erat diam interdum augue,
                        a consectetur ipsum massa sed enim. Nullam fermentum hendrerit dui. Nulla et eros sed odio facilisis
                        iaculis id ut eros. Phasellus facilisis non purus vitae ultricies. Curabitur at felis sed risus facilisis
                        porttitor. Aliquam vitae feugiat purus, non aliquam quam. Integer in tellus eget purus mollis efficitur
                        id ut ipsum. Donec egestas in ex vel rhoncus. Fusce sit amet eros ex. Donec facilisis neque eget
                        nisi tincidunt, eu pulvinar arcu vestibulum. Suspendisse sit amet urna egestas, lacinia ligula nec,
                        ultrices metus. Fusce rutrum lorem massa. Praesent lacinia ipsum vitae erat lobortis aliquam. Donec
                        tincidunt ante id sapien vehicula aliquet. Sed dolor metus, vulputate eu euismod et, commodo quis
                        turpis. Nam non nunc ac ante gravida porttitor eget vel orci.</p>
                    <p>Nulla sit amet congue turpis. Cras sagittis lacus sit amet nulla molestie, sit amet sollicitudin velit
                        dictum. Aenean a urna nec mi imperdiet molestie. Cras placerat arcu non condimentum elementum. Maecenas
                        maximus ultricies magna, sed hendrerit elit pulvinar non. Sed suscipit eros eu sollicitudin hendrerit.
                        Donec porta porttitor ullamcorper. Vestibulum vulputate nibh vel libero faucibus ornare. Curabitur
                        vehicula tincidunt quam, ac suscipit leo ullamcorper quis. Pellentesque pulvinar metus vel leo porttitor
                        facilisis. Morbi scelerisque consectetur justo nec placerat. Aliquam lorem lacus, gravida non tristique
                        nec, viverra sed massa. Integer luctus, dolor scelerisque mattis lacinia, erat diam interdum augue,
                        a consectetur ipsum massa sed enim. Nullam fermentum hendrerit dui. Nulla et eros sed odio facilisis
                        iaculis id ut eros. Phasellus facilisis non purus vitae ultricies. Curabitur at felis sed risus facilisis
                        porttitor. Aliquam vitae feugiat purus, non aliquam quam. Integer in tellus eget purus mollis efficitur
                        id ut ipsum. Donec egestas in ex vel rhoncus. Fusce sit amet eros ex. Donec facilisis neque eget
                        nisi tincidunt, eu pulvinar arcu vestibulum. Suspendisse sit amet urna egestas, lacinia ligula nec,
                        ultrices metus. Fusce rutrum lorem massa. Praesent lacinia ipsum vitae erat lobortis aliquam. Donec
                        tincidunt ante id sapien vehicula aliquet. Sed dolor metus, vulputate eu euismod et, commodo quis
                        turpis. Nam non nunc ac ante gravida porttitor eget vel orci.</p>
                    <p>Nulla sit amet congue turpis. Cras sagittis lacus sit amet nulla molestie, sit amet sollicitudin velit
                        dictum. Aenean a urna nec mi imperdiet molestie. Cras placerat arcu non condimentum elementum. Maecenas
                        maximus ultricies magna, sed hendrerit elit pulvinar non. Sed suscipit eros eu sollicitudin hendrerit.
                        Donec porta porttitor ullamcorper. Vestibulum vulputate nibh vel libero faucibus ornare. Curabitur
                        vehicula tincidunt quam, ac suscipit leo ullamcorper quis. Pellentesque pulvinar metus vel leo porttitor
                        facilisis. Morbi scelerisque consectetur justo nec placerat. Aliquam lorem lacus, gravida non tristique
                        nec, viverra sed massa. Integer luctus, dolor scelerisque mattis lacinia, erat diam interdum augue,
                        a consectetur ipsum massa sed enim. Nullam fermentum hendrerit dui. Nulla et eros sed odio facilisis
                        iaculis id ut eros. Phasellus facilisis non purus vitae ultricies. Curabitur at felis sed risus facilisis
                        porttitor. Aliquam vitae feugiat purus, non aliquam quam. Integer in tellus eget purus mollis efficitur
                        id ut ipsum. Donec egestas in ex vel rhoncus. Fusce sit amet eros ex. Donec facilisis neque eget
                        nisi tincidunt, eu pulvinar arcu vestibulum. Suspendisse sit amet urna egestas, lacinia ligula nec,
                        ultrices metus. Fusce rutrum lorem massa. Praesent lacinia ipsum vitae erat lobortis aliquam. Donec
                        tincidunt ante id sapien vehicula aliquet. Sed dolor metus, vulputate eu euismod et, commodo quis
                        turpis. Nam non nunc ac ante gravida porttitor eget vel orci.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://static.theultrasoft.com/parallaxie/parallaxie.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $(".parallax").parallaxie({
                speed: 0.55,
                offset: 0,
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hugocsl, valeu mesmo pela ajuda cara. Eu alterei removendo o fill-mode e direction. Acho que já melhorou bastante. Só não entendo a questão dos 5s, a imagem parece não figurar 5 segundos, mas acredito que isso se deva a divisão do tempo no keyframe, usei em 0% e 100% a mesma imagem, alternando para as outras imagens em 40% e 80%.
O tamanho das imagens estão diferentes só neste exemplo que montei no codepen, pois não tenho as imagens online que vou utilizar, ai usei uma imagem qualquer  e não me atentei ao fato de não estarem no mesmo tamanho., desculpe.
Valeu pela dida do Snippet tb.

Comment: @Quati_Maldito não fica 5 segundo pq vc tem 5s para a animação inteira! Se vc quer cada imagem com 5s e vc tem 3 imagens a animação deve ter 15s e não 5s... Vc tb tem que levar em conta que o tempo é o tempo total, incluindo a transição do fadein e fadeout da imagem na tela... Qualquer coisa estamos ai. Boa sorte no projeto